Announcing a Special Pro Tempore election for 2024
Summary: Monero Stack Exchange currently has no moderators. We will begin the nomination stage for a special election on Tuesday August 20, 2024 to bring in three new mods.
All moderators across the SE network were asked to sign a new version of the moderator agreement by August 8, 2024. Mods who chose not to sign by that deadline had to be removed from their positions. We thank the prior Monero SE mods for their contributions over the years.
Currently this site has no active mods, a situation which needs to be solved as soon as possible by holding a new election.  For full details of the election process, see the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange.
The timeline:

Starting on August 20, users can nominate themselves. Users can also ask questions on Meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the discussion and election tags.)

On August 27, if there are 4 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there are still fewer than 4 candidates, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to remove a nomination.)

If there are still fewer than 3 candidates at the end of the nomination period even after it is extended, we may need to seriously consider the on-going viability of the site.


If the election moves into the voting phase, I'll announce the results on Meta on Wednesday, September 4 (or September 11, if we need to extend the nomination period).


It is very important that community members step up and consider taking on mod roles, in order for the site to continue being a functional space for this community.
If you have any questions about the process, please post them in an answer here.

Considering how poorly the site has been doing recently, I expect the election to fail. In which case I fully expect the site to be taken out of its misery. Correct?
